# How to print the codes in python?

Tags: python

How does one print the lines of code?

Suppose we have here two variables.

```
var1 = 2*8
msg = "Answer is: "
```

What statement should i add here so that this program will print the source code?

Comment: print var1 this will the print the value of var1

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Maybe provide sample output and define your question better?

Comment: @lakesh I know how to print the values stored in the variables, i wanted to know what command will print me the codes i used when writing the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to print the lines of codes is through the use of the built-in functions.

```
   print open(__file__).read()
```

Or you could just write the code in string mode and simply print them. However that obviously won't be executable codes anymore once written in quotation marks.